# How to optimize the allocation of product aquisition

Tags: predictive-modeling, scikit-learn

The scenario is purchasing of a product or raw material from multiple suppliers on a regular basis, and the problem is how to best allocate order quantities among the suppliers.

For example need 100 units of the product in a certain time period.  Based on historical averages for example the allocation percents can be 50,25,15,10 among 4 suppliers.  But sometimes suppliers are impacted by circumstance and resulting split is like 60,30,5,5.  There is a re-allocation if one producer cannot meet the demand so requests get re-routed to the most productive suppliers in the time period.

There are other variables in play such as how busy the suppliers are with other clients, or even seasonal adjustments.  Some variables can be known, others are unknown.

How to optimize this problem so that the initial allocation is most accurate and re-allocation is minimized?

Side note: trying to understand if there is any tool or approach in Python Scikit-learn that generally can be used for this problem.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

To break the problem down, I think you are seeking to predict the capacity of the 5 suppliers ahead of time. So that you could allocate the order sizes for each supplier that is smaller than the capacity so that there is no need for reallocation.

However, I doubt that you would be able to know what is the full capacity of each supplier, as you have mentioned, each supplier also have other clients so you don't know how much more could each supplier handle, on top of your previous order.

As a (big) compromise, you could model as though each supplier is operating at 100% capacity when they serviced your past orders. With that, you have the series of Y to feed into your regression model. As for the inputs, you could add seasonality e.g. Time of year. I'm not sure as a outsider, you would have enough meaningful input variables to train the model. Maybe a naive approach of Mean(OrderSize) + 2StdDev(OrderSize) might work better.

Hope this helps.